# Multiple videos as backgrounds: HTML5 or YouTube?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I have a one page website that I would like to have multiple videos on. I want the videos to be full-width of the browser. I have 6 videos in total. I messed around with plugins that allow me to set an HTML5 video as a div background, but when I add multiple HTML5 videos to the page, the video quality is poor, and jumpy. I'd like to be able to autoplay the videos, and keep the audio functional. In regards to loading speed, playback quality, and overall best user experience, does anyone have any suggestions in order to accomplish this? Should I continue with the HTML5 video as a div background approach or try YouTube videos?

Comment: what is the div background stuff accomplishing? you can style the <video> tag using css to be any width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoplaying multiple videos at the same time on any website especially if they are full width of the browser will make most videos jumpy.  If you have them play one at a time you will probably not have that issue.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! I was planning on autoplaying the first video then kicking the other videos off as the user scrolls, but when I was testing I did, in fact, have multiple autoplaying at the same time. I will see what kind of improvement I get after making this change.